# Requires Scope Authentication on using Youtube API

Tags: html, css, angular, youtube-api, runtime-error

While using the youtube API to get the subscriptions,liked videos,upload videos and comments, and update the channel details of the authenticated user in our angular project using youtube APIs,we are getting 403 Forbidden error. It states that request had insufficient authentication scopes.

we have tried applying scope  and access token to the API but still we get this error.
Could any one help us with this error and provide suggestions based on it.
Here I have attached the  screenshot of the error message and our code.

Subscription.ts file

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { YoutubeService } from '../youtube.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-subscriptions',
  templateUrl: './subscriptions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./subscriptions.component.css']
})
export class SubscriptionsComponent implements OnInit {
  firstname:any;
  account:any;
  User: boolean=false;
  subscription:any;
  access_token:any;
  
  
  constructor(private service:YoutubeService) {
    this.firstname=localStorage.getItem('name');
    this.access_token=localStorage.getItem('access_token');
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.firstname);
    if(this.firstname != null)
    {
      this.User=true;
      console.log(this.User);
    this.service.GetSubscriptions().subscribe((res:any) => {
      console.log(this.firstname);
      this.subscription=res.items;
      console.log(this.subscription);
     });
  }
}

}
```

Service .ts :

```
   import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleLoginProvider } from 'angularx-social-login';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class YoutubeService {
  
  private APIURL = "https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/";
  private APIKEY ="AIzaSyB40HaKwd0VggftBq8R9sEwQx_NG5xOOWc";
  SocialAuthService: any;
  access_token=localStorage.getItem('token');
  reqHeader:any;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
    const reqHeader = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.access_token)
    .set('Scope', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly')
   }
 
  public GetSearch(name:string)
  {
    return this.http.get(this.APIURL+"search?part=snippet&key="+this.APIKEY+"&q="+name+"&type=video");
  }

  public GetChannel(username:any)
  {
    return this.http.get("https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&forUsername="+username+"&key=AIzaSyB40HaKwd0VggftBq8R9sEwQx_NG5xOOWc");  
  }

  public GetVideos()
  {
    return this.http.get("https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&chart=mostPopular&regionCode=IN&key=AIzaSyB40HaKwd0VggftBq8R9sEwQx_NG5xOOWc")
  }

  public GetSubscriptions()
  {
    return this.http.get("https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&mine=true&key=AIzaSyB40HaKwd0VggftBq8R9sEwQx_NG5xOOWc");
  }
  
  public GetPlaylist(id:any)
  {
    return this.http.get("https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&channelId="+id+"&maxResults=25&key=AIzaSyB40HaKwd0VggftBq8R9sEwQx_NG5xOOWc")
  }
}
```

Error Message:
[image: 403-Forbidden error]